# SSH : git special repository

Tags: git, ssh

I wrote a plugin for Grav CMS, to sync page with git. 
My git repository is self-hosted and didn't use SSH port 22.

I want to passthrough ssh config file. I see I can use 
`git config core.sshCommand`

I try this butseem doesn't work 
I get an error (on `git push`) :

> ssh: connect to host git.netime.fr port 22: Connection refused"
>    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm using docker withe docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

You don't have use the config file just because your git repo doesn't use port 22.

You can still do the normal way using `remote add`

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:22222/user/repo.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: > You don't have use the config file just because your git repo doesn't use port 22. no, i can write in with www-data user !